# Exposing AWS EC2 port on local machine port using node package tunnel-ssh

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel

In my AWS EC2 instance I have one API service running on port 3030. I want to access that service in my localhost:3030.
I want to use this npm lib [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh), my configuration object is like this:

```js
const sshConfigs = {
    keepAlive: true,
    username: 'ubuntu',
    host: 'ssh.server.host.com.br',
    port: 22,
    dstHost: 'ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
    dstPort: '3030',
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname, 'ssh_key', 'key.pem')
    ),
};
```

That worked perfectly to connect to an RDS host located on port 3306, but I can't make it work with a service running on EC2 machine.

I have all the information about the EC2 that may be necessary to access it.

**EDIT 1**

The API is running on the EC2 instance at port 3030 (to connect to the EC2 an SSH tunnel is required), on my local machine I want to access that API making a request to the API. I am not sure if SSH tunnels is the way to go for that, open to new sugestions.

Comment: Are you running this on an EC2 instance, or is it from a computer on the Internet? What is the configuration of the Inbound rules in the Security Group on the target EC2 instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Just added EDIT 1 to clarify that, could you please take a look?

Comment: What is the configuration of the Inbound rules in the Security Group on the instance that is running the API?

Comment: There is no configuration, previously I Openned port 3030 to all ips, just to check if it was working correctly, but now it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation appears to be:

- You have an Amazon EC2 instance in a public subnet (`Public-EC2`)
- You have an Amazon EC2 instance in a private subnet (`Private-EC2`) that is running an API on port 3030
- You wish to connect from your own computer (on the Internet) to the `Private-EC2` via SSH and Port Forwarding using `Public-EC2`

In this situation, your **Security Groups** should be configured as follows:

- The Security Group associated with `Public-EC2` should have **Inbound rules** that permit SSH connections from your IP address or the whole Internet (this appears to be configured correctly), and the default "Allow All" **Outbound rules**
- The Security Group associated with `Private-EC2` should have **Inbound rules** that permit connections on port 3030 from `Public-EC2` (That is, the security group should specifically reference the `Public-EC2` security group). You might also want to permit inbound connections for SSH so that you can login to the instance via `Public-EC2`